# Is a horizontal scroll bar for graphs available on Bokeh?

Tags: python, d3.js, bokeh

Bokeh:
Can anyone provide some guidance on creating the horizontal scroll bar similar to the one shown in the image below such? Does anything of the like exist?  Is this feasible without fiddiling D3.js?  Graph can be viewed at

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDP#

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [python-highcharts](https://github.com/kyper-data/python-highcharts) instead. The graph you showed is apparently using highcharts.

Comment: I also am interested in how to show a highcharts-like scroll bar with bokeh.

Comment: Theres' nothing built in, currently. But it is possible to write a custom extension to for that. If you're interested in discussing details I'm sure lots of people would be interested in the result. I'd be happy to help but the [public mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?pli=1#!forum/bokeh) is probably better for that than SO.